# Point does not exist in namespace System.Drawing

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie to C# and trying to run a sample C# program from a tutorial.

When I try to run the below code I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Point' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\Class1.cs  20  28  HelloWorld

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Nullable<bool> b = false;
            if (b.HasValue) Console.WriteLine("b is {0}", b.Value);
            else Console.WriteLine("b is not set");

            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 30);

            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your project have a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`? This is basically *exactly* what the error message is about.

Comment: How can I add a reference to System.Drawing.dll? Do I need to download the dll or how do I locate it in my machine and pin point it to the compiler?

Comment: In your VS, show the Solution Explorer->right click References->Add references->.NET->whatever

Comment: There is another [Point-structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.point.aspx) (from WPF) using double instad of int.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417594/cant-find-point-in-system-drawing

Answer (score 6):

In your Solution Explorer right click on References click on Add Reference click on the .NET tab and scroll to `System.Drawing`. It should work then.