# Can't find "Point" in System.Drawing

Tags: c#

As I know, **Point** are exist in namespace **System.Drawing**, but Visual Studio can't find it.

```
using System.Drawing;
class Flower
{
    public Point Location { get; private set; }
}
```

Error: Can't find name of type or namespace "Point"

**Edit 1:**
.Net 4.5.1

Comment: what .NET Framework are you using? Also did you try to add the assembly reference to System.Drawing.dll?

Comment: Does `System.Drawing.Point` work instead of just `Point`?

Comment: Did you add the assembly reference to System.Drawing.dll??

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Can't find System.Drawing.Point too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click in Solution Explorer on your Project's `References` entry and click on `Add Reference...`

[image: Context menu]

Make sure you're looking under Assemblies --> Framework, then find and check the checkbox for `System.Drawing`, then click OK.

[image: References]

From here, you can use`System.Drawing.Point` in your code.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. I'll upvote it in a few minutes of the technical reason. But why I should do it by hands. I thought, that when I write using System.Drawing, it must work without additional configuration.

Comment: I can have `MyNamespace.MyType` in an assembly that's installed, but unless that assembly is references, I can't use it. Some framework assemblies are added by default for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, you are missing a reference to `System.Drawing` in your project.  The reason this works in some project types and not others is that some project types, specifically Windows Forms projects, will automatically add the reference to `System.Drawing` for you.  While  other project types like Console App, Class Library, or WPF Application do not automatically have that reference, so you have to manually add it.