# How do I access the Point class in OpenTK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, opentk

Started making a game using Mono, I'm using OpenTK 2.0.0.  I was going to use Points for object positions (I don't foresee a need for floats), but I can't seem to access the Point class in OpenTK.  I see it [here](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/src/OpenTK/Math/Point.cs) but Visual Studio can't seem to find it and complains when I try to use it like this:

```
using OpenTK;

namespace Foo {
  class Bar {
    Point baz;
  }
}
```

I made sure I have the most recent version installed via NuGet.  The OpenTK Vector2 class seems to work under the same circumstances, but not Point.  Why?

Comment: Maybe `MINIMAL` was #defined in the build you're using?

Comment: I noticed that in the OpenTK source.  What is its purpose?

Comment: This is important if I want to support lightweight builds like for Android or something, right?  Unnecessary if I don't care about that, yeah?

Comment: My first comment was wrong -- I inverted the condition. `Point` will only be built if `MINIMAL` is defined, otherwise you're expected to use the `Point` structure in the `System` namespace.

Comment: VS can't seem to find that either.  The only namespace it suggests is Microsoft.XNA.Framework.  System is already being used.

Comment: Added a reference to System.Drawing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417594/cant-find-point-in-system-drawing
and it worked.  Why can't I just use "using"?

Comment: Because `using` is about putting namespaces into scope, not about specifying your project's references. These are two different mechanisms.